# How does std::merge work in C++?

Tags: c++, stl, merge

Below is the code taken directly from a link (given at the end) of the std::merge in C++. I understand what is happening, inside the while loop (the copy parts), but I don't understand when this loop will end. Because of the `while (true)` should this loop not run forever?

```
template <class InputIterator1, class InputIterator2, class OutputIterator> OutputIterator 
  merge (InputIterator1 first1, InputIterator1 last1, 
         InputIterator2 first2, InputIterator2 last2, 
         OutputIterator result)
{   
    while (true) {
        if (first1==last1) return std::copy(first2,last2,result);
        if (first2==last2) return std::copy(first1,last1,result);
        *result++ = (*first2<*first1)? *first2++ : *first1++;   
    } 
}
```

**http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/merge/**

Comment: Have you tried debugging it?

Comment: @Chandrika: Don't you see two `return` statements in the middle of the cycle, which, if executed, will certainly prevent the cycle from running forever?

Answer (score 4):

On each iteration either `first1` or `first2` are incremented, so at some point one of them will become equal to `last1` or `last2` respectively (provided the arguments are specified correctly), so one of the `return` statements will be executed.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to exit a loop:

1. The continuation condition becomes false.  Obviously that doesn't happen here, because the literal `true` will never change to false.
2. A branch from inside the loop to some outside location.  Statements that can do this include `break`, `return`, `goto`, `throw`, a call to the `longjmp` or `exit` functions, etc.  This code does have two `return` statements inside the loop.